# Is there any function in .net core 3.0 that can match url with its route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a string containing a URL and I want to get the route that matches this URL.

Let's say the URL string contains the value

`http://localhost/PerformOperation/accountId/Operation/operationId`

and I have route called "PerformOperations" that matches this url

`PerformOperation/{accountId}/{action}/{operationId}`.

How do I get this route? MVC obviously does this on every request but I don't know how I would do it manually. I have a list of Routes, and from the URL I will have to find the matched route.

Comment: Are `accountId` and `operationId` placeholders for actual values?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in methodology for something like this. You'd essentially have to bootstrap the entire routing framework and mimic a request coming through. What is your actual need here? Perhaps there's a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseEndpointRouting();

    //Your custom middleware that does something with routing data
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
    // let assume we are asking for http://localhost:18159/home/index/22
    var endpointFeature = context.Features[typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature)]
                                            as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature;

    Endpoint endpoint = endpointFeature?.Endpoint;

    if (endpoint != null)
    {
        var routePattern = (endpoint as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern
                                                                                    ?.RawText;

        // Example result : Name: AdRaker.Core.Web.Tracker.Controllers.HomeController.Index (AdRaker.Core.Web.Tracker) 
        var info1 = $"Name: {endpoint.DisplayName}";
        // Example result: Route Pattern: Home/Index/{id?}
        var info2 = $"Route Pattern: {routePattern}";
        // Example result: Metadata Types: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerAttribute, 
        // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DataTokensMetadata, 
        // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValuesAddressMetadata, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionFilter, 
        // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.SaveTempDataAttribute, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter
        var info3 = $"Metadata Types: {string.Join(", ", endpoint.Metadata)}";
    }

    // Forward data to next middleware
    return next();
});
[...]
```

First middleware is responsible for inspecting the incoming request and matching it to endpoint.Without it endpoint data will be always null.